# jquery hidden preload

Tags: jquery, preload

Here is my page http://equipe94.com/2009e.html

there is some tweek that append to the page (scroller and arrows)and some positionning

Do you have a way, to completely hide everything (just keep the background).. do the things , and show up the finished page ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not just set the css `display` property to `none`, and change it with JS when the document has loaded? If you're using [jQuery](http://www.jQuery.com) on your page, it could look like this:

CSS:

```
#mydiv { display: none; }
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#mydiv').show();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

To supplement Calvin's answer, images can be preloaded by adding in this function:

```
$.preloadImages = function()
{
  for(var i = 0; i<arguments.length; i++)
  {
    $("<img>").attr("src", arguments[i]);
  }
}
```

Then just telling it which images you want to be loaded:

```
$.preloadImages("image1.gif", "/path/to/blah.png", "some/other.jpg");
```

Put that code before the stuff you are loading in, as a courtesy.

Answer (score 0):

This type of question has been asked before. What you're talking about really isn't "preloading"--it's just obstructing the user's view of the page until the page is fully loaded. It doesn't make the page load any faster.

Just put the entire page inside of a container, and use CSS to set that container's display mode to `none`. Then simply change the container's display mode to anything other than `none` once the document is ready or the last image has been loaded:

```
var imgTotal = 10; // total number of images on your page
var imgCount = 0;

$("img").load(function(){
  imgCount++;
  if (imgCount == imgTotal)
    $("#container").show();
}
```

However, considering that your page loads in less than a second on my browser, I don't really see any point in this.

Answer (score 0):

it not exactly images, but page element that shift the problem...

i have css the body to hidden
and the last argument of my jquery is css:visible

work great.. 2 second loading, and everybody show up !

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would use a DOM ready to set it's display to none, then show it on $(window).load

Otherwise, if they don't have JS enabled, they'll never see a thing!

I've noticed your site is still viewable too without JS, good job!