# Jquery offline preload

Tags: jquery, preload

Here is my html page http://equipe94.com/2009e.html

I do somee tweek to the page, and it make the page reposition (scroll and  arrow)

Do you have a method that hide everything (except the background), do the thing that make the page shift, and show everything now at the right place

Answer (score 0, accepted):

-- sorry double post.. -- the only question : [jquery hidden preload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/775008/jquery-hidden-preload)